# MySql update table with replace string1 string2

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, database

I need replace `string1` to `string2` in column big table. My table weight is1.7GB. For update I will use:

```
UPDATE table 
SET column = REPLACE( column, 'search', 'replace' );
```

So, I have several questions:

1. Will table lock during procedure? Should I hide the public part of my site?
2. How long will this procedure be executing?
3. How better to run this? Maybe 'screen'? if my ssh connection will closed.

MySQL 5.5.53

Comment: And what is the reason why you need to use replace instead of using where clause directly into it? Your question is all depend on your machine capabilities.. and database structure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my case:

```
UPDATE table SET column=REPLACE(column, 'search', 'replace')  WHERE column LIKE "%search%";
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't run replace on all the rows of the table. 
Instead add a where condition as @reds said in the comments. 
This will make your update much more efficient and is the correct way to do it.

```
UPDATE table SET column = 'replace' where column = 'search';
```

Comment: I agree with @reds :D

Comment: Date type this column 'text', I need search 'string' in text and replace all matches.